# Go to the error state and keep the URL to the state generating the error

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using this to catch errors and redirect to an error page

```
module.run(function ($state, $rootScope, translateService) {
    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
        $state.go("app.error");
    });
});
```

But this moves to the error state and changes the URL. I want to go to the error page and keep the URL to the page with the error.

I've tried using the location option,`$state.go("app.error", null, { location: false })`, but it keeps the URL of the state I'm coming from and not the one with the error.

Can I somehow go to the error state and keep the URL or go to the error state and then change the URL back to the URL of `toState`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by sending the error information to the error state and then set the url with $location.path there.

```
module.run(function ($state, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
        $state.get("app.error").$error = {
            toState: toState,
            toParams: toParams,
            fromState: fromState,
            fromParams: fromParams,
            message: error.message,
            stack: error.stack
        };

        $state.go("app.error");
    });
});

module.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state("app.error", {
        url: "/error",
        resolve: {
            error: function () {
                return this.self.$error;
            }
        },
        templateUrl: "app/error.tpl.html",
        controller: function ($state, $scope, $log, $location, error) {
            if (error) {
                $location.path($state.href(error.toState, error.toParams).replace(/^#/, ""));
                $log.error(error.message, error.stack);
            }

            $scope.error = error;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this does the trick (I found this trick some time ago, it wasn't documented):

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $state.go("app.error", {}, { location: false });
});
```

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki
look at the part about $stateChangeError

Comment: Wait sorry. This will only work for direct url navigation like with href or direct browser location bar update.
Not with a $state.go.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the accepted answer, I did a small change that allowed me to retain the error url but attempt to go to the homepage (or whatever state you want) when the user tries to refresh:

```
controller: function ($state, $scope, $log, $location, error) {
        if (error) {
            $log.error(error.message, error.stack);
        }else{
            $state.go('app'); // or app.home or whatever
        }

        $scope.error = error;
    }
```